# How to convert m/d/y to a BigQuery timestamp?

Tags: google-bigquery

What's the easiest way to convert dates formatted as m/d/y (aka mm/dd/yyyy) to a TIMESTAMP in BigQuery?

Answer (score 2):

If you use standard SQL in BigQuery, it becomes even simpler by using PARSE_TIMESTAMP function:

```
SELECT ds, PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%m/%d/%Y', ds)
FROM (SELECT '03/23/2015' ds)
```

(details how to enable standard SQL in BigQuery: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Try REGEXP_REPLACE():

```
SELECT ds, 
       TIMESTAMP(REGEXP_REPLACE(ds, r'(..)/(..)/(....)', r'\3-\1-\2')) ts
FROM (SELECT '03/23/2015' ds)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ds, 
  TIMESTAMP(REGEXP_REPLACE(ds, r'(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})', r'\3-\1-\2')) ts
FROM (SELECT '03/23/2015' ds)
```